# lightning-record-edit-form for custom lead conversion page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lead-conversion

I'm planning to create a custom lead conversion page using lightning-record-edit-form. Would it be possible? Will I be able to override the buttons action using this form?
TIA

HTML:

```
     <template>

        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Convert Lead</h2>        
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-scrollable_y" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}        
            object-api-name="Lead">

            <lightning-messages>
            </lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field data-field="Salutation" field-name="Salutation" > </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field data-field="FirstName" field-name="FirstName" > </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field data-field="LastName" field-name="LastName" > </lightning-input-field>                        
            <lightning-input-field data-field="Company" field-name="Company" > </lightning-input-field>
          

            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </div>

       
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={cancel}>Cancel</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleConvert} type="submit"> Convert</button>
        </footer>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import convertLead from '@salesforce/apex/apexController.convertLead';

export default class CustomLeadConversion extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; //leadId passed from aura quick action cpe_Custom_Convert    

    @api convertedAccount = { 'sobjectType': 'Account',
                              'Name': 'Converted Account' 
                            };
    @api convertedContact = { 'sobjectType': 'Contact',
                              'Name': 'Converted Contact'
                            };
    @api convertedOpportunity = { 'sobjectType': 'Opportunity',
                                  'Name': 'Converted Opportunity' 
                                };
  

       handleConvert(){
        console.log('convert button is clicked'); //this is OK  
        console.log(this.recordId);

        convertLead({ld: this.recordId, acc: this.convertedAccount, con: this.convertedContact, opp: this.convertedOpportunity})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }      
}
```

APEX:

```
public with sharing class apexController{
          
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String convertLead(Id ld, Account convertedAcc, Contact convertedAccCon, Opportunity convertedAccOpp){
        System.debug('lead ' + ld);
        System.debug('account ' + convertedAcc);
        System.debug('con ' + convertedAccCon);
        System.debug('opp ' + convertedAccOpp);
        
        //Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        
        try{
           
            System.debug('this.isUpdateLead ' + ld);
                   
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(ld);
            
            if(convertedAcc != null && convertedAcc.Id != null){
                System.debug('attached account ' + convertedAcc.Id);
                lc.setAccountId(convertedAcc.Id);
            }
            if(convertedAccCon != null && convertedAccCon.Id != null){
                System.debug('attached contact ' + convertedAccCon.Id);
                lc.setContactId(convertedAccCon.Id);
            }
            if(convertedAccOpp != null && convertedAccOpp.Id != null){
                System.debug('attached opportunity ' + convertedAccOpp.Id);
                lc.setOpportunityId(convertedAccOpp.Id);                
            }
            
            LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
            
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());               
            
            Lead convertedLead = [SELECT convertedContactId, convertedOpportunityId FROM Lead WHERE Id =: ld];
           
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
        
        return 'converted';
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to if you override the submit event on the form. To get more specific help, please post the code you have and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: I am currently receiving an error: FATAL_ERROR System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 1